# DNS zone names level restrictions

Tags: dns-zone

I'm researching a topic, but can't find any info about it, so I decided to ask here.
I read 2 RFCs, but didn't saw anything about that. I presume there is non, but I need to be sure.

Is there a limitation on the level of the DNS zone names e.g. can a DNS zone name be of sixth level domain name like sub.sub.sub.sub.sub.domain.com with its own DNS zone file of course?

Many thanks,
Yani

Comment: which RFC's did you read? Because there are dozens. The earlier ones aren't too terse and quite enlightening.

Comment: (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) and (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFC 1034:

> To simplify implementations, the total number of octets that represent
>   a domain name (i.e., the sum of all label octets and label lengths) is
>   limited to 255.

So that's 253 characters for the total domain name.
That is the limit, so it's however many you can press into that.